# How to make a polygon div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am able to make a normal square div and a triangle div in CSS. But I don't know how to make such a shape with a single div. Can anyone help me out ?

Also I want this to spread to the entire width of it's parent but  `border` properties don't support percentages. ( eg `border-left: 160px solid transparent;` )

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.v-div {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 160px solid transparent;
  border-right: 160px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid #f00;
}

.box{
   height: 80px;
   width: 320px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="v-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a polygon. What else change you want?

Comment: Though it's already mentioned in my question above, I'm currently using two divs. I want to make this with a single div

Comment: @mrid  I think, I solved your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it with `:after` pseudo classes. If you uncomment the `:before` in this example you get a hexagon

```css
#hexagon{
  position: relative;
  height:100px;
  width:50%;
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
#hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 0;
  background-color:green;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 57.7%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use clip path css property

```css
#clippedDiv{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 35%, 50% 70%, 0 35%, 0 0);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 35%, 50% 70%, 0 35%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="clippedDiv"></div>
```

for more shapes you can visit http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: can you tell me how to make this work on firefox ? since firefox doesn't support clippath property

Comment: has anyone ever told you that you are a genius? This was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

use :after css selector.

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
margin-top: 100px;
}

  .box {
width: 100px;
height: 55px;
background: red;
position: relative;
}
.box:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -25px;
left: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @priya, it works fine. Though I have one lil question. How can I expand this div to it's parent's width without breaking the layout. As I have to use this on a responsive webpage.

Answer (score 1):

```
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><polygon fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" points="850,75  958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5" /></svg>
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).